# Error : 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute '_n_features'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am predicting the values from classification model by loading .pkl file. It works in my local, but throws an error in AWS lambda function. The pkl file on local and AWS are same, so the issue should not be in pkl file. Also, I read the pkl file correctly .
Error : 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute '_n_features'

```
ind_var = pd.DataFrame({"a":1328, "b":12.0, "c": "MAP")
with BytesIO() as data:
            s3.Bucket("xxxxxx").download_fileobj("model.pkl", data)
            data.seek(0) 
            model = joblib.load(data)
 print(model.predict(ind_var))
```

Code used for pipeline

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps= ["scaler", StandardScaler())])

categorial_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),("onehot", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [("num", numeric_transformer,numeric),("cat",categorial_transformer, cat )])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just got to know by trial and error that this issue occurs due to the differences in the version of the libraries. We can check the version of libraries in different environments by using requirements.txt

Comment: Good answer re: sklearn version differences, but note that requirements.txt is not necessarily what's installed in an environment unless someone ran `pip install -r requirements.txt`. From the command line in the environment `pip list` one way to check what's actually installed